# Show that this map is well-defined on cohomology

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras, homology-cohomology, quotient-spaces, differential-graded-algebras

I'm following [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9409063.pdf) paper, trying to understand Corollary 5.

Essentially, there is a Lie Bracket $[,]:C^*\otimes C^*\to C^*$ on a cochain complex $C^*$ such that the the differential $d$ of the complex is a derivation of the bracket, i.e.

$$d[x,y]=[dx,y]+(-1)^{|x|}[x,dy].$$

The author says that from this it is easy to see that this map takes cocycles to cocycles and is independent of the choice of representative of the cohomology classes. I can see that if $dx=0=dy$ (both $x$ and $y$ are cocycles) then $d[x,y]=0$ by the above identity, so the bracket takes cocycles to cocycles. My problem comes when trying to show that the value on different representatives of the same cohomology class is the same on cohomology.

I can compute the bracket of another representative using linearity

$[x+da,y+db]=[x,y]+[x,db]+[da,y]+[da,db]$

If I assume that $[x,da]=[x,0]=0$, then I would be done, but I think $[x,da]=[x,0]$ is part of what I want to prove. Otherwise I would need to show that $[x+da,y+db]-[x,y]$ is a coboundary. But this difference is

$[x,db]+[da,y]+[da,db]$

and I don't see how this is $d(something)$.

Comment: The authors do not state that $d$ being a derivation for $[-,-]$ implies $[-,-]$ being well defined in cohomology. They say "It easy to observe Fact (i) from the definition of the dot product and the differential in any operad with multiplication (see (4) and (5)) and from the fact that $d$ is a derivation of the bracket (11)". So did you try applying the actual definitions of the dot product and $d$ given in (4) and (5)?

Comment: @Christoph The last part of the paragraph is "from the fact that d is a derivation of the bracket", so I understand that it should follow from that, since the first part of that paragraph seems to refer to the product, but maybe that's not what they mean. I will try to do it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to describe the $[x,db]+[da,y]+[da,db]$ as a coboundary.

It is $d((-1)^{|x|}[x,b]+[a,y]+[a,db])$. Here's the computation using the derivation property, note that $x$ and $y$ are cocycles, so they vanish when $d$ acts on them

$$d((-1)^{|x|}[x,b]+[a,y]+[a,db])=(-1)^{|x|}[dx,b]+[x,db]+[da,y]+(-1)^{|a|}[a,dy]+[da,db]+(-1)^{|a|}[a,ddb]=$$

$$[x,db]+ [da,y]+[da,db]$$

as I wanted.

P.S.: mathematicians, if something is easy, do it or at least indicate it, this is easy once you see it, but I don't think it's so obvious.